# Who schedules threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, cpu, scheduling

I have a question about scheduling threads. on the one hand, I learned that threads are scheduled and treated as processes in Linux, meaning they get scheduled like any other process using the conventional methods. (for example, the Completely Fair Scheduler in linux)

On the other hand, I also know that the CPU might also switch between threads using methods like Switch on Event or Fine-grain. For example, on cache miss event the CPU switches a thread. but what if the scheduler doesn't want to switch the thread? how do they agree on one action?

I'm really confused between the two: who schedules a thread? the OS or the CPU?

thanks alot :)

Comment: The OS schedules threads on virtual cores. The CPU schedules instructions on execution units.

Comment: This really depends a lot on what OS (and what version of that OS) and what thread library is in use, so it can't be answered specifically for all cases. There have been implementations where thread scheduling was done entirely by the thread library, as well as those where it's handled exclusively by the OS kernel. In some cases there's a 1:1 mapping between threads and what the OS kernel schedules (an LWP or VCPU or whatever), and in other cases the mapping is N:1 or even N:M...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is both.

What happens is really *fairly* simple: on a CPU that supports multiple threads per core (e.g., an Intel with Hyperthreading) the CPU appears to the OS as having some number of virtual cores. For example, an Intel i7 has 4 actual cores, but looks to the OS like 8 cores.

The OS schedules 8 threads onto those 8 (virtual) cores. When it's time to do a task switch, the OS's scheduler looks through the threads and finds the 8 that are...the most eligible to run (taking into account things like thread priority, time since they last ran, etc.)

The CPU has only 4 real cores, *but* those cores support executing multiple instructions simultaneously (and out of order, in the absence of dependencies). Incoming instructions get decoded and thrown into a "pool". Each clock cycle, the CPU tries to find some instructions in that pool that don't depend on the results of some previous instruction.

With multiple threads per core, what happens is basically that each actual core has two input streams to put into the "pool" of instructions it might be able to execute in a given clock cycle. Each clock cycle it still looks for instructions from that pool that don't depend on the results of previous instructions that haven't finished executing yet. If it finds some, it puts them into the execution units and executes them. The only major change is that each instruction now needs some sort of tag attached to designate which "virtual core" will be used to store results into--that is, each of the two threads has (for example) its own set of registers, and instructions from each thread have to write to the registers for that virtual core.

It is possible, however, for a CPU to support some degree of thread priority so that (for example) if the pool of available instructions includes some instructions from both input threads (or all N input threads, if there are more than two) it will prefer to choose instructions from one thread over instructions from another thread in any given clock cycle. This can be absolute, so it runs thread A as fast as possible, and thread B only with cycles A can't use, or it can be a "milder" preference, such as attempting to maintain a 2:1 ratio of instructions executed (or, of course, essentially any other ratio preferred).

Of course, there are other ways of setting up priorities as well (such as partitioning execution resources), but the general idea remains the same.

An OS that's aware of shared cores like this can also modify its scheduling to suit, such as scheduling only one thread on a pair of cores if that thread has higher priority.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply.
I want to see if I understand you correctly: what your saying is that from the OS point of view, there are 8 cores, so the scheduler assign a thread for each "core".

so, each core will be assigned with 2 threads, and now inside the core itself the CPU is the one who decides which of the two runs? for example the CPU is running one, and an event happen, so he switches to other?

one more thing: say thread 1 is assigned to core 1, can the scheduler change this later?
and if the scheduler decides to perform context-switch, all threads must be replaced right?

Comment: Yes, inside a single core the CPU decides which instructions to run (regardless of which thread they came from). Yes, a thread can (and often will) run on one core at one time, and a different core at a different time. When the scheduler doe a context switch, it could potentially switch all the threads that are running (but depending on how many threads are ready to run, it could also re-run exactly the same threads, or switch some and leave others running).

Comment: It is also worth noting that some processors (e.g., some IBM POWER implementations) allow the OS to configure the hardware thread scheduling (e.g., assign thread priority). In some implementations of multithreading (Sun's SPARC T3, if I recall correctly), the "thread number" can influence performance because resources are partially partitioned. With such hardware, the OS could choose to run two lower priority threads in one thread group and only one thread in another; a similar effect is possible for Intel x86 by scheduling two lower priority threads on one core and only one on another core.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: Good point--I've edited to at least mention the general idea of the CPU being aware of thread priorities.

Answer (score 0):

The OS handles scheduling and dispatching of ready threads, (those that require CPU), onto cores, managing CPU execution in a similar fashion as it manages other resources.  A cache-miss is no reason to swap out a thread.  A page-fault, where the desired page is not loaded into RAM at all, may cause a thread to be blocked until the page gets loaded from disk.  The memory-management hardware does that by generating a hardware interrupt to an OS driver that handles the page-fault.

Comment: I don't understand your answer and how does it answer my question :(